# How do I identify a variable name in a piece of code

Tags: regex, axapta, x++

I am trying to write a halstead complexity measure in X++ (language isn't important) and I think the best way of doing this is by using regex on the source.

I have managed to do 90% of it but am struggling on variable names.

How do I identify a variable name in a piece of code.

Given the following piece of code

```
public void main()
{
    int a, b, c, av;
    className class;
    strFmt("%1 %2 %3", a, b, c);
    av = (a + b + c) / 3;
    info("avg = %1");*/

    if(a)
    {
        a++;
        class.add(a);
    }
    else
    {
        b++;
        class.subtract(b)
    }

    this.main();
}
```

I expect to be returned "a" "b" "c" "av" "class"

With the halstead it needs to count the instances of them. The way I was thinking is by storing the above in a list and then using whatever is in the list in a regex query. Catering for all possible uses of a variable would be insane.

Comment: Use a language parser.

Comment: Regular expressions are mostly unsuited for parsing languages which are not regular. I can't think of a programming language which is regular.

Comment: @deceze [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29)

Comment: x++ does have some best practice checkers in but its incredibly unreadable. I will take a look but it sounds like what I am wanting is impossible. It's just annoying that I have managed to get the other 90% done.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I wouldn't call that a *regular programming language* per se. ;o)

Comment: That's why regexen are unsuitable. They get you most of the way there, but fail in many many edge cases.

Comment: Could you make a regex using a list of non-valid variable name characters around your variable names e.g. `(?:^|[\n+;-\\\.])a(?:[\n+;-\\\.]|$)`

Comment: A person has a problem. He says "I know. I will solve this problem with regexp!". A person has two problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up cheating with the solution. I had already got all of the operators information such as int/public/methods etc... so I just used substituion on the source and then ran the following regex which found me the operands for the metric.

```
'_?\w+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)|".+"'
```

There were some really good answers on here so I am going to look into using a hybrid of them to improve the implementation at a later date but for now we are getting the information we need and it seems to work for all cases we have tested it on.

If anyone is interested the regex I used for the operators is the following

```
(?i)\(|\{|\w+(?=(\(|:|\.))|\w+(?=\s\w)|(break|continue|return|true|false|retry|asc|breakpoint|desc|null|pause|throw|ttsAbort|ttsBegin|ttsCommit)(?=;)|((try|catch|else|by|do)(?=\n))|(\+=|-=|>=|<=|==|!=|=|\+\+|--|<<|>>|&&|\|\||\*|\/|\+|-|~|&|\^|\||>|<|!|\?|::|:|\.)+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

It has all the reserved keywords which are not covered by the first 4 statements, I also got the list of operators which x++ use.

It will need some modification to be used in other languages but considering other languages have better ways of dealing with these things you probably don't need it.

Thanks for all your answers

Answer (score 2):

I think you would have to reflect on the AOT in order to get the different variables.

You could use reflection with `TreeNode` or maybe you could use the XPPCompiler to get info on the objects you're processing to help:

`info(strFmt("%1", new xppCompiler().dumpClass('salesformletter')));`

Comment: Could you not have commented before :) That looks like it would have provided me with a lot of info. I'm not sure whether it would be too processor heavy to get this to work but I may mess about when I have time and see the performance difference between my current solution and this.

Answer (score 2):

This question made me sort of curious about how to do this and I came across this great post that has a custom AX tool to measure complexity plus a 175 page grad paper written about it.

http://bojanjovicic.com/complexity-tool-dynamics-ax-2009/

I'm experimenting with it now and looking how I can build onto it.

Comment: Thats really useful, I will have to spin up a clean environment to mess around with that and see how I can use it to make a more robust system.

Answer (score 2):

I'm back with the actual answer!  Use the `SysScannerClass` and `TreeNode` object to correctly parse the code.  Here's a beautiful sample I wrote that should make it cake.

```
static void JobParseSourceCode(Args _args)
{
    TreeNode        treeNode = TreeNode::findNode(@'\Data Dictionary\Tables\SalesTable\Methods\find');
    SysScannerClass sysScannerClass = new SysScannerClass(treeNode);
    int             symbol;
    int             curLine;
    str             lineStr;  

    setPrefix("Scanning " + treeNode.treeNodePath());
    for (symbol = sysScannerClass.firstSymbol(); symbol; symbol = sysScannerClass.nextSymbol())
    {
        if (curLine != sysScannerClass.line())
        {
            curLine = sysScannerClass.line();
            lineStr = sysScannerClass.sourceLine(curLine);
        }

        // NOTE: symbol corresponds to macros in #TokenTypes
        info(strFmt("Line %1: %2\t(Col %3): '%4' - MacroValue: %5, [%6]", curLine, lineStr, sysScannerClass.col(), sysScannerClass.strValue(), symbol, xppScanner::symbolClass(symbol)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice parsing of the source code, but it does not tell you which tokens are variables.

Comment: Well I'm not going to do 100% of the work, but that part is fairly easy though once you've got this far. You look for when `symbol` returns `5` then use a combination of AOT Reflection, regEx, and basic logic.  There aren't a ton of cases left, especially since this identifies things like `{` with a matching type and correctly ignores comments and comment blocks.

Comment: Thats pretty clever. Since starting to write this code metrics project in AX i've discovered there is a lot of crazy methods you can use to do some really interesting tools. This does solve the base question but I don't think it would be usable in a halstead implementation because variable types, identifiers and method calls go into one map and variable names go into the other. and it would be quite innefficient if not impossible to do that in this method I think. BUT this has given me an idea for something else! Thanks

Comment: Well this alone wouldn't do it, but you'd mix it with AOT reflection.  It gets pretty close. Did you look in the `#TokenTypes` macro to see how you could identify everything exactly? And you'd just be looking at #STD_ID(5) symbol items.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the example does not quite qualify as X++ source, because `class` is a reserved word and cannot be used for a variable name.

Besides that a crude search for `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]+` would give you all strings which *could* be a variable name. But without a full parser you would have trouble determining whether it is a keyword, class name, table name et cetera or a genuine variable name.

You could also use `TextBuffer` to [tokenize your source](http://gotdax.blogspot.dk/2009/07/tokenizing-string.html):

```
static void TokenTest(Args _args)
{
    str src = @'
        public void main()
        {
            int a = 7, b = 11, c = 13, av;
            info(strFmt("%1 %2 %3", a, b, c));
            av = (a + b + c) / 3;
            info(strFmt("avg = %1"));
            this.main();
        }    
    ';
    TextBuffer t = new TextBuffer();
    t.ignoreCase(true);
    t.setText(src); // Set the text to break in to tokens
    while (t.nextToken(false,' (){}.,:;!=+-*/\n')) // The delimiters to search 
    {
        info(t.token());
    }
}
```

This will not work with strings and comments of course.

There is even an undocumented [Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg921493.aspx) kernel class to play with!

Maybe the best choice would be to integrate with the [cross reference tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa626961.aspx), it has done the splitting for you!

I am afraid your remaining 10% may take 90% of your time!

Comment: This is essentially my implementation I have used the text buffer but there are 2 components of the halstead metric so I have had to use a couple of regex inside the nextToken loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex101.com to play with regex. I think you can play with the look-ahead `(?=...)` and the look-behind`(?<=...)` groups:

This regex will match all your variables:

```
/(?!void)(?<=[ \(])[a-z]+(?=[, ;+*\/\)])/
```

And here the proof:

http://regex101.com/r/hS9dQ6/2

Comment: Thanks for the site. I have been using http://www.regexr.com/# which has recently changed and now doesnt support negative look-behinds.

This regex just seems relevant for this piece of code though, such as parameter variables will not be picked up, so main(int _b) it will pick int up not _b

Also x++ does something a little strange and finds the int in my code above. I believe x++ uses the standard .net regex.

Comment: Yes of course you need to extend the list of exceptions and there are many of them like all the keywords of your x++. What I suggest is to use a syntaxic analyser like Lex or Flex. Those programs are made to parse and analyse source code and extract the relevant parts.